# What does a double membership operator do?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've no prior experience with SQL*Plus, and can't find an answer to this on Google.

I'm wondering what the ".." operators do in SQL*Plus. I cannot find any simple explenations for it in any kind of documentation, or online.

```sql
PROMPT CREATE TABLE &&OWNER..POINT
```

This is an example of where I see it used. Sorry if you need more context here, but I can't show the whole script because it might be sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref458):

> If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character.

You have substitution variable `OWNER`, and you're trying to produce a `SCHEMA.TABLE` pattern. As an example I'll define that variable, and just get the substituted value from dual:

```
define OWNER=MYSCHEMA

select '&&OWNER.POINT' from dual;

old:select '&&OWNER.POINT' from dual
new:select 'MYSCHEMAPOINT' from dual

'MYSCHEMAPOIN
-------------
MYSCHEMAPOINT
```

The period in `&&OWNER.POINT` has been interpreted as a separator and terminator for the variable name, only the `POINT` part is seen as the 'append characters', and so the final result doesn't have a period at all - and isn't what you want.

As that single period is being consumed, you need to allow for that and then add a second, actual, period that is retained - so that it is still treated as part of the 'append characters':

```
select '&&OWNER..POINT' from dual;

old:select '&&OWNER..POINT' from dual
new:select 'MYSCHEMA.POINT' from dual

'MYSCHEMA.POIN
--------------
MYSCHEMA.POINT
```

which looks much better.

So `..` isn't an operator. The first `.` is part of the substitution variable syntax - and is often omitted - while the second `.` is part of the final value you are forming. After the substitution that is just a normal part of the [schema object naming](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Syntax-for-Schema-Objects-and-Parts-in-SQL-Statements.html), and not specific to SQL*Plus at all.